# VB Alpha Numeric condition

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project which has various field and few forms to input data.

There is one input field which should not allow less then 7 characters.

What i want is, "I want to validate input".

For example, The Field name is customerid. input data must be in "AB1234C" format.

Comment: So input must be 2 random letters, 4 numeric and 1 random character? This is do-able , but ***what have you tried***?

Comment: input must be 2 random letter then 4 random number then 1 random letter

Comment: please help me out..

Comment: You didn't answer my question above...

Comment: i dont know what to do ..I am a beginner .

Comment: I am a beginner and i dont know what i can use

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to do this. One way would be to create a validation function and call it when the form is submitted, before you do any actions.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    If ValidInputs() Then
        'Submit form...
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ValidInputs() As Boolean
    If tbCustomerID.Text.Length < 7 Then
        MessageBox.Show("The Customer ID must be more then 6 characters.")
        tbCustomerID.Focus()
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: **Less than 7** not 6. Also this doesn't validate nothing besides checking length, a function for just this isnt needed. He needs a specific format, you don't mention this at all. Clearly the OP hasn't showed an attempt at anything and by posting an answer like this doesn't encourage people to try... Please don't encourage this type of behaviour...

Comment: Yup it should be < 7, I'll fix it.
I did not realize that he wanted that format.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll keep that in mind when posting answers.

Comment: input rule must be 2 random letter then 4 random number then 1 random letter is acceptable